# invoice pdf add image

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I try to add image in invoice it's working fine but i need to add after total

```
$image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/bar.png';
if (is_file($image)) {
    $imageWidth = 812; $imageHeight = 450;
    $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
    $y=$imageHeight /2.5;
    $page->drawImage($image, 35,$y, 35+ $imageWidth / 1.5, $y + $imageHeight/2);

}
```

also I created Dynamic Image Based on Order id then how to get that name

```
$custom = $invoice->getIncrementId();

        $image = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/.'$custom'.png';
if (is_file($image)) {
    $imageWidth = 812; $imageHeight = 450;
    $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image,$imageWidth,$imageHeight);
    $y=$imageHeight /2.5;
    $page->drawImage($image, 35,$y, 35+ $imageWidth / 1.5, $y + $imageHeight/2);

}
```

[image]

How to add this after total what mistake i done here?

Comment: you need to set co-ordinates for image .

Comment: are you need after Grand Total right???

Comment: Yes after Total which means last part of pdf